# PDO no encuentra los drivers en PHP 7

Tags: mysql, php7, pdo, apache, php5

Un saludo a toda la comunidad, verán estoy usando wamp mientras hago unas practicas con conexión a base de datos mySQL mediante PDO y todo iba bien mientras usaba PHP 5.4.3 sin embargo recientemente actualice a PHP 7.4.7 y repentinamente el mismo programa que estaba probando dejo de funcionar, arrojando el siguiente error:

"could not find driver"

Pense que seria una incompatibilidad de las versiones de PHP pero tras investigar un poco use phpinfo() y note que PDO no tiene definida ninguna base de datos con la que trabajar en mi php 7:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo al cambiar a mi php 5 en wamp si que hay bases de datos asignadas a PDO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad es que ya llevo un rato investigando y viendo php.ini y ya no se que mas podría hacer para solucionar esto. Espero su ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano.

Aquí el código que conecta con la base de datos MySql por pdo:

```
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:bdname=pruebas; host=localhost', 'root', '');
        $conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIO_PASS WHERE USUARIO = :USER AND CLAVE = :PASS";
        $resultado = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
        $user = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["user"]));
        $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));
        // $resultado -> bindValue(":USER", $user);
        // $resultado -> bindValue(":PASS", $password);
        $resultado -> execute(array(":USER" => $user, ":PASS" => $password));
        $registros = $resultado -> rowCount();
```

Comment: Eso suele ocurrir cuando no encuentra la extensión, quizá porque para PHP 7 estará en otra carpeta. Puedes escribir `php -m ` en la consola y te informará con más detalle sobre los errores de inicio. Revisa también las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7086859/5587982). En la mayoría de los casos el problema era la ruta de la extensión, no la extensión PDO en sí misma.

Comment: ciertamente e pensado que esa puede ser la causa del problema ya que me doy cuenta que en phpinfo() me especifica la ruta de php y me indica que esta en un directorio en apache: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin\php.ini donde no existe la carpeta ext.

Answer (score 1):

me paso por aquí para indicar que ya logre resolver el problema con la conexión de php 7 con pdo en mysql y vengo a explicar como lo hice por si alguien tiene el mismo problema en las mismas circunstancias que yo.

Primero que nada mi problema se dio cundo pase de php 5.4.3 a php 7.4.7 en ese instante php 7 dejo de reconocerme los drivers que conectan mediante pdo con mysql sin embargo cuando regresaba a php 5 el problema ya no estaba, al correr el programa en el que trabajaba con php 7 me disparaba el siguiente error:

"could not find driver"

Como ya lo explique antes, el mensaje es claro, no esta encontrando los drivers correspondientes, esto lo verifique al introducir phpinfo() y correrlo en el navegador en donde compare mi php 5 con mi php 7:

phpinfo() en php 7.4.7:

[image: phpingfo() en php 7.4.7:]

phpinfo() en php 5.4.3:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me desconcertó porque al ver las extensiones que estaban habilitadas en los archivos php.ini de cada una de las versiones de php se encontraban disponibles las extensiones php_pdo_mysql.dll y en la carpeta ext de ambos también estaban dichos archivos .dll.

Pero note que la extensión donde esta guardado php que me mostraba phpinfo() era diferente de donde están las versiones de php en wamp, que es lo que uso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que me dirigí a dicha carpeta y ahí también había un archivo php.ini, el problema se resolvió al cambiar la versión de php que manejaba este archivo en una de las ultimas lineas a:

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.4.7/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"
```

Que antes era:

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"
```

También realice por la linea 816 del archivo (en mi caso era esa linea pero por lo que e visto puede variar un poco):

Antes era:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"
extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/"
```

Y se cambio a:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"
extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.4.7/ext/"
```

Final mente tras todo esto el problema se soluciono y pude realizar la conexión a mysql por PDO sin problemas y al volver a usar phpinfo() con php 7 me salia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es todo, espero que a alguien le ayude esto, soy algo nuevo en php así que esto me rompió la cabeza durante un par de días. Adiós.

Comment: Entiendo, perdón aun soy algo nuevo en stackoverflow, pero la respuesta que me soluciono el problema es la que acabo de publicar y no me deja seleccionarla sino hasta mañana.

Answer (score 0):

Abre el archivo `php.ini` de la configuración (lo veras más arriba de la página que muestras imagen); busca `extension=` allí encontraras `extension=pdo_mysql` pero con `;` al inicio; quitalo: es decir, esta así:

```
;extension=pdo_mysql
```

debe quedar:

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

Lo que puse es conforme esta en mi php.ini que es la misma versión que muestras indicas tienes.